# Hazelcast sql query with JSON_QUERY and filter

Tags: sql, json, hazelcast

I try to do a SQL query on Hazelcast map.
ata in the map is in Json format.

How can I do a query with json filter ? I need to get all data with hasEvents == true

I tried to do this filter :

`select JSON_QUERY(this, '$.data.field1.hasEvents?==true') from products`

but it doesn't work

I expect to get all the entries in the map where data.field1.hasEvents = true

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have this table structure

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (id INT NOT NULL, data VARCHAR(100), PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO product (id,data) VALUES (1, '{
  "field1": {
    "hasEvents": true
  }
}');

INSERT INTO product (id,data) VALUES (2, '{
  "field1": {
    "hasEvents": false
  }
}');
```

Your SQL should be something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM product WHERE JSON_QUERY(data, '$.field1.hasEvents') = 'true'
```

Comment: Thanks Orçun. The database is as follow : 

CREATE MAPPING products TYPE IMap OPTIONS('keyFormat'='varchar', 'valueFormat'='json');

When I do :
select * from products where JSON_QUERY(this, '$.field1.hasEvents') = 'true' 

I have this error : Cannot apply '=' operator to [JSON, VARCHAR] (consider adding an explicit CAST)

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: I will post a full example that works for me in another answer

Answer (score 0):

I am using hz **5.4.0-SNAPSHOT** in this example. Link to the complete example is here
https://github.com/OrcunColak/hzjetclient/blob/c8b526d0160ab3a2eb576716e314a262898feef4/src/main/java/com/colak/jet/sql/json/json_query/JsonQueryIMapTest.java

This is the test skeleton

```java
public static final String MAP_NAME = "product";

public static void main(String[] args) {
  log.info("Starting HZ Server");

  // Start server
  HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = getHazelcastServerInstance();
  populateMap(hazelcastInstance );
  createMapping(hazelcastInstance );
  testSelect(hazelcastInstance );
  hazelcastInstance .shutdown();
  log.info("Test completed");
}
```

This method creates an embedded hz server

```java
HazelcastInstance getHazelcastServerInstance() {
  Config config = new Config();

  // Add JetConfig
  JetConfig jetConfig = config.getJetConfig();
  jetConfig.setEnabled(true);
  jetConfig.setResourceUploadEnabled(true);
  return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

Let's populate the map

```java
void populateMap(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
  IMap<String, HazelcastJsonValue> map = hazelcastInstance .getMap(MAP_NAME);
  map.put("1", new HazelcastJsonValue("""
                {
                  "field1": {
                    "hasEvents": false
                  }
                }
                """));

  map.put("2", new HazelcastJsonValue("""
                {
                  "field1": {
                    "hasEvents": true
                  }
                }
                """));
}
```

This one creates a mapping. I have copied from your example

```java
void createMapping(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
  String createMappingQuery = format("CREATE OR REPLACE MAPPING %s Type IMap OPTIONS('keyFormat'='varchar', 'valueFormat'='json')",
                MAP_NAME);

  SqlService sqlService = hazelcastInstance.getSql();
  sqlService.executeUpdate(createMappingQuery);
}
```

Now select from the mapping that uses underlying IMap

```java
void testSelect(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
  SqlService sqlService = hazelcastInstance.getSql();
  try (SqlResult sqlResult = sqlService.execute("SELECT __key, this FROM product WHERE JSON_QUERY(this, '$.field1.hasEvents') = 'true'")) {
  if (sqlResult.isRowSet()) {
    String[] columnNames = getColumnNames(sqlResult);
    int numberOfColumns = columnNames.length;
    for (SqlRow sqlRow : sqlResult) {
      for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
      Object columnValue = sqlRow.getObject(columnIndex);
      log.info("{} : {}", columnNames[columnIndex], columnValue);
      }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I can see from the output that it selects the entry having key = 2